# Python3: Como calcular o número de dias úteis entre duas datas?

Tags: python-3.x

Gostaria de saber como pode ser feito no Python 3 o cálculo da quantidade de dias úteis entre duas datas.

Comment: Encontrei esta boa fonte para feriados nacionais: http://www.anbima.com.br/feriados/feriados.asp

Answer (score 5):

Espero que ainda seja útil,

Existe uma biblioteca chamada [workalendar](https://pypi.org/project/workalendar/), que faz o que você está procurando de forma simples.

Basta importar e definir o calendário brasileiro.

```
import datetime
from workalendar.america import Brazil

cal = Brazil()
cal.holidays(2019)
```

A função abaixo retorna o dia útil após entrar com a data inicial e a diferença de dias desejada:

```
def data_dias_uteis(data_inicial, dias):
    return cal.add_working_days(data_inicial, dias).strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

print data_dias_uteis(date(2019, 01, 26), 35)
15/03/2019
```

Comment: Ótima sugestão de biblioteca!

Answer (score 4):

então, como está na resposta do Diego, saber o número de dias entre duas datas, basta subtrair dois objetos do tipo `date` e pegar o atributo `days`. Agora, quanto a dias úteis: - contar os sábados e domingos é tranquilo - o date tem como verificar o `.weekday` , e aí você pode fazer contas de mais ou menos, correndo o risco de um erro, ou fazer um laço  e contar os dias.

Fazer um laço de uma data até a outra é uma excelente oportunidade de criar um iterador em Python: uma definição de função com a palavra chave `yield` que então poderá ser usada diretamente num for:

```
def iterdates(date1, date2):
    one_day = datetime.timedelta(days = 1)
    current = date1
    while current < date2:
        yield current
        current += one_day
```

E aí dá para fazer:

```
a = datetime.date(2018,1, 25)
b = datetime.date(2018, 2, 10)

for d in iterdates(a, b):
    if d.weekday() not in (5, 6):
        print (d, d.weekday())
```

Ou, para contar os dias:

```
dias_de_semana = sum(1 for day in iterdates(a, b) if day.weekday not in (5,6))
```

(weekday 5 e 6 são sábado e domingo)

Feriados, é óbvio que é complicado: ou você acha uma API que te responde qualquer feriado no país desejado no mundo (é possível que haja algo assim no google calendar), ou faz um hard-coding dos feriados nacionais e compara com os mesmos.

Por exemplo, você pode fazer um dicionário:

```
feriados = {
    "confraternização universal": date(2018, 1, 1),
    "carnaval": date(2018, 2, 13),
    ...
}
```

e aí usar algo parecido com a expressão anterior:

```
dias_uteis = sum(1 for day in iterdates(a, b) if day.weekday not in (5,6) and day not in feriados.values())
```

Comment: Olá @jsbueno obrigado pela explicação e desculpe-me a demora!
Como sou novato em Python e esse foi um problema que tentei criar por conta própria, acho que o meu nível de conhecimento nesse instante não está me permitindo avançar, mesmo com a sua ajuda. Talvez eu esteja pulando alguns degraus hehe.

Abs

Comment: Caso seja útil (pun not intended): https://api.workingdays.org/1.2/api-documentation.php#non_working_days

Answer (score 0):

Pode usar essa biblioteca.

```
from datetime import date
from = date(2008, 8, 18)
to   = date(2008, 9, 26)
delta = from - to
print delta.days
```

Comment: Olá, Diego!

Valeu pelo post! No entanto gostaria de saber em "dias úteis" (ou seja, desconsiderando sábados, domingos e feriados) e não em dias corridos.

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime as dt
from workadays import workdays as wd

#   Diferença de dias úteis entre duas datas

d1 = dt.date(2021, 11, 1)
d2 = dt.date(2021, 11, 26)

print(wd.networkdays(d1, d2))
```

a Resposta do calculo será 17 tirando os finais de semana e Feriados.

O cogigo abaixo Exibe a lista de feriados do Brasil e de São Paulo

```
import datetime as dt
from workadays import workdays as wd

for date in wd.get_holidays(country='BR', state='SP', years=range(2020, 2022)):
    print(date)
```

2020-01-01
2020-01-25
2020-02-24
2020-02-25
2020-04-10
2020-04-12
2020-04-21
2020-05-01
2020-06-11
2020-07-09
2020-09-07
2020-10-12
2020-11-02
2020-11-15
2020-11-20
2020-12-25
2021-01-01
2021-01-25
2021-02-15
2021-02-16
2021-04-02
2021-04-04
2021-04-21
2021-05-01
2021-06-03
2021-07-09
2021-09-07
2021-10-12
2021-11-02
2021-11-15
2021-11-20
2021-12-25

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).